# No Network Devices Available after fresh install of 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I have completed a fresh installed of Ubuntu 12.04, but my Intel 82578dc is not being detected.

Please can anyone help me to install the network driver.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install some additional drivers. Go to `System Settings` -> `Additional Drivers` and if a network driver is listed there, install it.